# Why do I get two different outputs when I use different functions?

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
df1<- structure(list(Score = c(26,  46, 62, 57, 18, 16, 44, 37, 47, 32, 71, 72, 
39, 85, 39, 77, 82, 34, 73, 79, 82, 29, 30, 33, 61, 18, 15, 22, 30, 15, 17, 50,
34, 67, 46, 73, 10, 62, 20, 81, 55, 69, 52, 78, 61, 14, 59, 37, 60, 55, 31, 11,
13, 30, 68, 60, 61, 69, 20, 47, 81, 62, 76, 43, 42, 10, 36, 54, 56, 49, 15, 7,  
48, 11, 51, 32, 55, 80, 13, 57, 55, 70, 16, 85, 40, 75, 45, 7,  46, 19, 81, 35,
63, 30, 16, 71, 50, 15, 81, 55, 46, 27, 64, 29, 25, 79, 70, 13, 27, 14, 62, 53,
26, 53, 74, 48, 73, 68, 82, class = "data.frame")))
```

I have used the following function to get the decile:

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(quantile = ntile(-Score, 10))
```

I have used the `StatMeasures` package to calculate the decile. I have used:

```
df2<- decile(vector = Score, decreasing = TRUE)
```

but I get two different deciles using these two functions. It is very confusing. Which one is correct? Have I missed something? Can any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n_tile` is meant for roughly placing values into 10 bins / buckets. It goes by rank, i.e first n/10 rank goes into 1 , next n/10 goes into 2 and so on. Hence when you have ties around the decile value, it might go into different bins:

First we get back your calculation:

```
library(StatMeasures)
library(dplyr)

df1 = data.frame(
Score = c(26, 46, 62, 57, 18, 16, 44, 37, 47, 32, 71, 72, 39, 85, 39, 77, 82, 34, 73, 79, 82, 29, 30, 33, 61, 18, 15, 22, 30, 15, 17, 50, 34, 67, 46, 73, 10, 62, 20, 81, 55, 69, 52, 78, 61, 14, 59, 37, 60, 55, 31, 11, 13, 30, 68, 60, 61, 69, 20, 47, 81, 62, 76, 43, 42, 10, 36, 54, 56, 49, 15, 7, 48, 11, 51, 32, 55, 80, 13, 57, 55, 70, 16, 85, 40, 75, 45, 7, 46, 19, 81, 35, 63, 30, 16, 71, 50, 15, 81, 55, 46, 27, 64, 29, 25, 79, 70, 13, 27, 14, 62, 53, 26, 53, 74, 48, 73, 68, 82)
)

df1 = df1 %>%
mutate(quantile1 = ntile(Score, 10)) %>%
mutate(quantile2 = decile(vector = Score))
```

We look at your decile values:

```
quantile(df1$Score,seq(0,1,by=0.1))
  0%  10%  20%  30%  40%  50%  60%  70%  80%  90% 100% 
 7.0 15.0 21.2 30.4 39.2 48.0 55.0 61.6 70.0 78.2 85.0
```

And where the two rankings differ:

```
df1[df1$quantile1 != df1$quantile2,]
    Score quantile1 quantile2
3      62         7         8
20     79         9        10
30     15         2         1
71     15         2         1
81     55         7         6
98     15         2         1
100    55         7         6
116    48         6         5
```

We look at one example:

```
df1[df1$Score==48,]
    Score quantile1 quantile2
73     48         5         5
116    48         6         5
```

If you want deciles, the first method by `n_tile` is incorrect, because 48 goes into 2 bins. So use the decile function from `StatMeasures`.

Comment: If you just need to divide your data into ten parts, n_tile is fine. But if I want to use the decile as a ordinal variable, say for regression, then you need to use a proper decile, so that ties get a consistent value, agree?

Comment: @User20100, the decile is defined as the value at every 0.1 interval of your ranked data. For example, you have 100 data points, first decile is the value at rank 10. Proper decile means, you bin your data according to decile values, and not simply cutting your data into 10 parts. If you look under the code for decile in Statmeasures, it uses cut and quantile, which is exactly how we would define deciles, quantiles etc.